# Jenkins plugin : error attempt to register a second PermissionGroup when install plugin

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins version : 1.642.4
Plugin : Selenium Plugin 2.53.1

I have updated the Selenium plugin (5.4.1 => 2.53.1) but after the restart of Jenkins I don't see the menu "Selenium Grid".
The Selenium plugin is not in the Installed plugin.
I see it only in Available menu.

When I try to install it (v2.53.1) I get this error :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1328)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install selenium plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:485)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1324)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to load hudson.plugins.selenium.PluginImpl from selenium
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:424)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:476)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:418)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to register a second PermissionGroup for hudson.plugins.selenium.PluginImpl
at hudson.security.PermissionGroup.register(PermissionGroup.java:135)
at hudson.security.PermissionGroup.<init>(PermissionGroup.java:59)
at hudson.plugins.selenium.PluginImpl.<clinit>(PluginImpl.java:99)
... 13 more
```

I think the old plugin is not properly removed but I didn't see it in Installed menu.

Thanks

Julien

Comment: how you resolved this issue? I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by deleting the older ownship.xml config file and  install the plugin.  Then it works. Because I want to install the job and ownership plugin.

I guess that there is a older Selenium plugin config file. So you can try to delete your config file for Selenium plugin.